# Как выключить viewPager?

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-fragment

Ситуация такая,есть окна во viewPager и в одном из этих окон можно запустить фрагмент,и в момент когда фрагмент находиться на экране мне нужно отключить возможность проматывать экраны во viewPager, как это сделать?Может есть какой-нибудь метод у viewPager который выключает его?

Comment: Посмотрите по этой ссылке: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку